# How to check git if folder has been changed

Tags: git, powershell, deployment

I have a Powershell script that deploys a number of projects. But since both the number of projects and the time to deploy each project are rather large, I'd like to only deploy them when I need to: when there's a change in version control. We have this set up on the development server, but I'd like to also do it on local machines, without installing Octopus or TeamCity.

How to ask in a powershell script if Git has made any changes within a folder?

Edit: I'd need to know whether there have been any changes since the last deployment. A listener on updates coming through git, or saving deploy times of each project and comparing that to the latest update on that project would work.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I might suggest looking at the [source code for posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git). From what I understand, it just calls `git.exe` and parses the output/return codes (but I haven't looked too closely).

Comment: What are you trying to check exactly? Whether there are changes in the upstream repository that aren't in your working directory? Whether your working directory is different than the HEAD of your current checked-out branch? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$changes = git whatchanged --since 2015-12-22
if($changes | Select-String $dbName)
{
  #Deploy database because there's been a change
}
```